# CNN Model Outputting All Zero's

Tags: tensorflow, ocr

I'm pretty new to machine learning and am having trouble with creating my first TensorFlow convolutional neural network. I'm using datasets from http://etlcdb.db.aist.go.jp/ and trying to get my network to classify handwritten Japanese kanji.

After training, I ended up with a testing accuracy of 0.93 and a validation accuracy of 0.94. However, for every testing input I pass into my network, I'm getting an output of all 0's, even with inputs from the original dataset.

Where did I go wrong? I'm passing in images that have already been preprocessed and normalized. Thank you so much for your help.

Below is the relevant code:

````
creating dataset ----------------------------------------------------------

IMG_HEIGHT = 92
IMG_WIDTH = 92
BATCH_SIZE = 10

training_set = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    IMAGES_PATH,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=420,
    validation_split=0.10,
    subset="training"
)

validation_set = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    IMAGES_PATH,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    color_mode="grayscale",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=420,
    validation_split=0.10,
    subset="validation"
)

my model ------------------------------------------------------------------

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(92, 92, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(PReLU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(PReLU())
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(6000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(3040, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile("adam", 
               loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
               metrics=['accuracy'])

prediction script --------------------------------------------------------

im = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

im = np.atleast_3d(im)
im = tf.image.resize(im, [92, 92])
im = np.expand_dims(im, 0)

model = keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)

output = model.predict(im)
print("guesses")
for num in sorted(output[0]):
    if (num > 0.5):
        print(chr(int(class_keys[num], 16)))

print("best guess")
print(np.argmax(output[0]))
print(chr(int(class_keys[np.argmax(output)], 16)))
```
````

Comment: You trained a multi-label model or multi-class? Because I see a `sigmoid` activation at the end instead of a `softmax`, so you're not getting normalized class probabilities but instead each output can be in $[0,1]$

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the problem.